# Number of Crossings on a Graph with cn edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Show there exists a family of graphs, universal constants $c$ and $c'$ s.t. for each graph with at most $cn$ edges, $n$ being the number of vertices, there are at least $c'n^2$ crossings.

I have tried to use complete graphs as complete graphs have ~$cn^4$ (n choose 4) crossings and ~$n^2$ (n choose 2) edges but this does not satisfy the condition of each graph having at most $cn$ edges. Complete bipartite graphs do not work for the same reason. I am stuck to think of which kind of graph has this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a graph consisting of a complete graph $K_t$ and $n-t$ isolated vertices, for suitably chosen $t$.

Note that complete graphs actually have crossing number less than $\binom n4$, but the crossing number inequality still gives an $\Omega(n^4)$ lower bound for them, so this shouldn't affect you except in the choice of $c$.

Comment: sorry might be a dumb question but how does this relate to the problem? because the graphs have to have cn edges (n being number of vertices) so complete graph aways have $Ω(n^2)$ edges?

Comment: A complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\Omega(n^2)$ edges. Here, I'm suggesting a complete graph on only $t$ of the vertices: that has $\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$ edges. You should choose $t$ to satisfy your constraint.

Comment: got it thank you